# массив символов С++

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

```
void showText1 (char str[])
{
      cout << str << endl;
}

void showText2 (char *str)
{
      cout << str << endl;
}
```

Почему выводит весь массив символов(всю строку)? Если там будет,допустим, массив целочисельный,то выведет всего лишь адрес первого элемента.

Comment: Заметьте, что `char str[]` (в качестве аргумента функции) на самом деле `char * str`, т.е. эти две функции совершенно одинаковы.

Comment: Потому что `str` в аргументах обоих функций по сути указатель на первый элемент ?

Comment: Не по сути, а в прямом смысле, массивы в параметрах функций всегда деградируют до простых указателей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из-за традиционной строки C, которая представляет собой массив `char`, оператор вывода `<<` для типа `const char *` перегружен так, чтобы выводить строку...